# Is there a way to include a file in your git repository but have sites like github ignore it in the code base analysis?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Currently, I have a repository that I keep up to date with all my coursework and everything I do school related to programming. Well, I have stored in this repository .gcode files which I used for 3D printing. The issue is however, given the size of a .gcode file they largely overpower everything else in the code analysis.

This feature is useful to me because I like to be able to view just how much I tend to use languages to solve problems; so I like to be able to see all of the languages and not jsust 99.8% G-Code and 0.2% "Other"

I figured I could just use a .gitignore for an end all be all but then I'd only have those files saved locally into my repository and often I work from a lot of different computers/VMs and like to have access to these files in my repository.

Comment: Store the files you want to exclude in a different repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. GitHub [uses](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-repository-languages) the [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) to recognize repository languages. As per the Linguist documentation, you can [use a `.gitattributes` file](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes) to [override default settings](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides).

In your case, a suitable way would be to mark your `.gcode` files as [vendored](https://github.com/github/linguist#vendored-code). Suppose you have a directory `dir` with the `.gcode` files, your `.gitattributes` file would be:

```
dir/* linguist-vendored
```

You could also match by extension.

Note that it might take some time for the changes to take effect. This is [because](https://github.com/github/linguist#how-linguist-works-on-githubcom):

> **How Linguist works on GitHub.com**
>
> When you push changes to a repository on GitHub.com, a low priority
>   background job is enqueued to analyze your repository as explained
>   above. The results of this analysis are cached for the lifetime of
>   your repository and are only updated when the repository is updated.
>   As this analysis is performed by a low priority background job, it can
>   take a while, particularly during busy periods, for your language
>   statistics bar to reflect your changes.